# Virtualization technology showing disabled by Windows 10 and Ubuntu 19.10 even though enabled in BIOS

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, bios, virtualization, intel-core2

Here is my System Config:

- Dell OptiPlex 755
- Intel Core 2 Duo
- NVIDIA GeForce 8400GS Graphics
- 6 GB RAM
- Latest updated BIOS
- **Virtualization supported** x64 Host

I enabled Virtualization, VT for Direct I/O, Trusted Execution on my BIOS.
[image: virtualizaation is on in my BIOS]

Even though enabled in my BIOS, this seems to be disabled, according to my operating systems(Windows 10 and Ubuntu 19.10)
I updated BIOS to the latest firmware, version A22 for the OptiPlex 755 only to find that problem still exists.
[image: ubuntu KVM disabled]

Same is with Windows 10
[image: windows VT-x diabled]

Answers for both Ubuntu and Windows are very appreciated.
Please help me!
**Edit**: Take a look at cat /proc/cpuinfo

:flags : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht tm pbe syscall nx lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl cpuid aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl ***vmx*** smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm lahf_lm pti tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority dtherm 
 As you can see, it contains vmx

I'm running a Windows 10 Enterprise edition(insider preview) Hyper-V is enabled in the windows features list. I have enabled everything related to virtualization in programs and features.

Comment: It doesn’t appear like you have installed Hyper-V within Windows, if you do not have at least Windows 10 Professional it cannot be installed.

Comment: Can you share a `cat /proc/cpuinfo` please ? The line `flags` should contains `vmx` to get KVM working.

Comment: @binarym Take a look at this                                                                      :flags  : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht tm pbe syscall nx lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl cpuid aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm lahf_lm pti tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority dtherm
As you can see, it contains vmx

Comment: @Ramhound I'm running a windows 10 enterprise edition(insider preview) Hyper-V is enabled in the windows features list. In fact, I have enabled everything related to virtualization in programs and features.

Comment: You need SLAT (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Level_Address_Translation) to run Hyper-V, and as far as I know, Intel Core 2 Duo CPUs don't support it (https://www.petri.com/check-cpu-slat-support).

Comment: Your screenshot indicates Hyper-V isn’t installed.  Are you sure you have Hyper-V installed?  Instead of a comment edit your question with the required information necessary to answer your question

Comment: Windows 10 Hyper-V won't work without SLAT.  The only edition of Hyper-V that did was Windows Server 2008/Hyper-V Server 2008.  2008R2 introduced the SLAT requirement. In other words, you can't use Windows 10 and Hyper-V on a C2D.  Try VirtualBox, although 6GB of RAM will really limit your use cases.